# Using Velocity.js for SVG animation with graphics included as HTML object tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, velocity.js, object-tag

How do you use Velocity.js with an SVG graphic that is included with an HTML object tag (which is realistically how complex graphics would be used).

Basically, include the graphic:

```
<body>
  <div id="graph">
    <object id="objSvg" type="image/svg+xml
       data="./diagram-arch-server-SRS-CH.svg"></object>
```

Then, the following methods do not work:

```
$("#server-webserver-4266").velocity({ x: "+=200", y: "25%" });
$("#objSvg").find("#server-webserver-4266").velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 });
```

I am using Velocity.js v1.4.3 with jQuery v3.1.1 latest versions.
I have searched extensively for a solution and the Velocity documentation only includes examples with inline SVG (lame!).

Comment: When you import SVG via an `<object>` tag, the SVG exists in it's own DOM as the content document of the element. jQuery can't/won't traverse that.

Answer (score 0):

So, to Pointy's point (in the above comment), here is a **solution** that uses Javascript to access the proper SVG element, then jQuery to apply the Velocity.js method:

```
// refer to the HTML in the original post, then the following script works!
myObj = document.getElementById("objSvg");
myContent = myObj.contentDocument;
myServer = myContent.getElementById("server-webserver-4266");
$(myServer).velocity({ x: "150", y: "-=75" });
$(myServer).velocity({ fillGreen: 255, strokeWidth: 2 });
```

Thank you Pointy!